# Applying for a job while just starting another

Tags: applications, germany, holidays

I'm going to start a new job at company A soon, after two months of unemployment. The work contract says I'm not entitled to ask for days off during the first six months. Besides, within this period there are a couple of days (before/after bank holidays) on which the company is shut down, and for which employees have to take a day off mandatorily.

This job I'm going to start is mostly a better-than-nothing option, which I accepted because life began to be difficult for me. Now I've seen today the one job advertisement from company B I've been waiting for the past weeks. (Literally: from a friend working there I knew it would come some day, but he couldn't tell when.) This job would be much better for me than the one I'm about to start, and I guess I'd also fit very well to the job profile. So I'm pretty confident I'd be invited for an interview if I apply, and I am very tempted to apply. After interview, I guess I have a 30% - 50% chance of being hired. (Company B is in the public sector, so the have to respect equal opportunities regulations which don't benefit me personally.)

My question is: How can I go to an interview at company B when I can't ask for a day off at company A?

Comment: If possible you can simply arrange to go after work, during the lunch break or early in the morning. This of course heavily depends on the travel time between company A and company B.

Comment: @Gianluca Not really an option, travel time would be about 1 hour one-way.

Comment: Then try to arrange a phone interview, at least for the first one. If you should pass it, then you can explain your problem. If company B is interested in you, a way will be found. But 1 hour travel time is really not so much for an after work interview in my opinion.

Comment: Is company B also closed during bank holidays?

Comment: @ Kepotx On bank holidays: Very likely so, it being in the public sector. "Around" bank holidays: Can't tell right now.

Comment: @Gianluca: You're right with after work. Perhaps I could leave a little early at A to make a late appointment at B. No option however for the lunch break ;-)

Comment: The answer is simple.   At company "A" you "can't" take a day off.  But you can take a day off *without pay*.  So do that.

Comment: @Fattie Are you sure about that? There is no specific privilege to take off unpaid days when your working contract says you cannot take days off. You can certainly *ask* and maybe they'll agree, but you make it sound like that is an option that is always open... and it's not.

Comment: @nvoigt , I get what you mean but it's not a military organization.  Put it this way: say as a matter of fact you took one day off, and then politely alerted the manager/bookkeeper "I was not here Monday, so of course, don't pay me for Monday."  What can they do?  They can fire you.  (You can't, eg, go to jail, get beaten, etc.)  The worst that can happen is they can fire you.  It's extremely unlikely that would happen, and in all events the person is leaving anyway.

Comment: uh... if you don't show up and have no explanation during your probation period, they **will** fire you. Probably on the spot. That is probably the worst breach of contract that does not involve a criminal court.

Comment: +1 @Fattie. ProcrastinatorSaved - are you all right? You look a bit unwell (hint, hint). It's easier to beg for forgiveness than to ask for permission.

Comment: @nvoigt , to be clear (sorry if I made a typo "then" in one of the long comments), of course - obviously - you would tell them on (say) Wednesday that you can't come in (say) Thursday morning (and, of course, you won't be paid for that time due to your contract).  (Confusingly, all of this is *exactly* what you say in your answer - in fact "dot 3" !  So, we are in total agreement ! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A good way to work within these constraints:

- See what your companies overtime policies are. Many people will structure their work week so they work 9 hours Monday through Thursday and leave after lunch on Friday in their 40 hours work week. This is probably your best bet because it requires little explanation.
- Ask the other company for an interview outside office hours. In the private sector that is normally not a problem. As they are in the public sector... I cannot say. But it cannot hurt to ask.
- Ask for unpaid time off. Do not go into details, just say you have a private appointment. If they insist, tell them it's with your tax accountant, "Schornsteinfeger", your landlord sending people to verify your smoke detectors work or otherwise boring stuff that happens to everybody in regular intervals.

## Slightly unethical:

- Interview early, then come in late to work and claim you were stuck in traffic or your alarm did not work. Although a lie, it's not a bad one, because they did not pay you. You still acknowledge it's your fault and you will need to work the lost hours at a later time. Obviously it will not leave a positive impression during your probation period.

## Completely unacceptable:

- Claim you are sick. Sick time in Germany is paid. Not only is it a lie, you also claim *payment from company A* for the time you lied to them and interviewed at company B. From my point of view, that's fraud, plain and simple.

Comment: Indeed, the third dot-point here is totally correct.   You don't have to "lie" - simply state that you have to take care of "accounting business", "personal paperwork", "a legal matter" or similar.  (That is all, actually, true!)

Comment: I completely agree with your last point.  That's what made me ask the question in the first place. I'm gonna try out your first three suggestions.